# private or protected class properties

Tags: unit-testing, coding-standards

I'm looking at a class in CRM_Utils_Cache [here specificly](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/fa938177202b0ef376e00b6cbe8be3814ef1cd28/CRM/Utils/Cache/ArrayCache.php#L42) and it looks exactly like what I need to write some unit tests against my extension.

The issue is that the `$cache` array is `private` rather than `protected`...

This means I can't extend this class into a test mock that allows my unit tests to manipulate and observe the cache state.

For this reason I'm wonder if there is a downside to changing this (and maybe other) properties to `protected`?

Comment: I see there is a get() and set() public function to store and retrieve values in `_cache`.  Are you not able to use them ?

Comment: Not to count the cache entries or inspect without knowing what the key is @jitendrapurohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think submitting a PR to make this variable protected would be perfectly reasonable.

Alternatively, there is a way to [access private properties in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) for the sake of unit testing via [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). It's slightly cludgy but it does work.

Comment: mmm - hard to know which to prefer of those 2 methods - wasn't aware of reflection technique - it seems like a reasonable approach for unit testing where you're allowed to do naughty things with mocks?

Comment: Yea but in this case I think making the variable protected really wouldn't hurt anything. Go ahead and submit the PR and save the Reflection in your back pocket, you'll probably find a use for it later.

Comment: cool thanks for the advice! PR: [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9605)